# Não mostra a 1 linha do array vazio usando o angularJS asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, array

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--inserindo a meta tag de keywords onde definimos as palavras chaves-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--descrição do nosso site-->
    <meta name="description" content="Sistema" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--inseri um logo para o meu sistema <!-https://www.iconfinder.com -->
    <link href="../Content/images/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Sistema</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- adicionado o css do carousel -->
    <link href="~/Content/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        angular.module("ListaDados", []);
        angular.module("ListaDados").controller("ListaDadosCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.app = "Dados que serão inseridos";
            //criando um array
            $scope.numeros = [
                { nJogo:"", valor:"" }
            ];

            $scope.adicionar = function (numero) {
               $scope.numeros.push(angular.copy(numero));
               delete $scope.numero;
            };

            $scope.apagar = function (numeros) {
               $scope.numeros = numeros.filter(function (numero) {
                    if (!numero.selecionado) return numero;
                });
            };


            $scope.isNumeroSelecionado = function (numeros) {
                return numeros.some(function(numero){
                  return numero.selecionado;
                });
            };


        });
    </script>

</head>
```

Ná página

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Partial("_navbarInterno")

{{numeros}}

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Número: </th>
            <th>Valor: </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-class="{'selecionado negrito':numero.selecionado}"  ng-repeat=" numero in numeros">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="numero.selecionado" /></td>
            <td>{{numero.nJogo}}</td>
            <td>{{numero.valor}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



<div class="container droppedHover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <input class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="número" maxlength="4"  type="text"  ng-model="numero.nJogo" />
            <input class="form-control input-sm"   placeholder="valor" maxlength="5" type="text"  ng-model="numero.valor" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-click="adicionar(numero)" ng-disabled="!numero.nJogo || !numero.valor">Adicionar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block " ng-click="apagar(numeros)" ng-show="isNumeroSelecionado(numeros)" >Apagar</button>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container droppedHover">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Estracao")" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left">
                    <span>Retorno</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Css:

```html
.selecionado{
    background-color:yellow;
}

.negrito{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: De onde estão vindo os dados da função 'adicionar'? Eles estão chegando corretamente? Caso não tenha verificado, aplique um log para a propriedade `numero` e veja como estão os dados.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, fiz a alteração do código da pergunta, adicionei todo o conteúdo de forma que fique mais fácil o entendimento, está me retornando [{"nJogo":"","valor":""}] assim que abre a tela, agradeço se poder ajudar.

Comment: Sim, consegui entender. Mas ainda tenho algumas dúvidas. Os valores a serem colocados naquela array, ou seja o `nJogo` e `valor` devem vir de onde? De um banco de dados? Ou será preenchido manualmente? Pois por enquanto você está apenas criando a array vazia e somente se o usuário interagir com o formulário é que vai haver o preenchimento.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, correto, os valores vem da interação do usuário manualmente, o problema é que vem a 1 linha do array em banco, sem ter uma interação, eu queria  vazio, eu vou tentar postar uma imagem para ficar mais fácil o entendimento, agradeço

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, adicionei uma imagem, veja se ficou mais fácil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece por que você criou a array e já criou um elemento vazio, veja:

```
$scope.numeros = [
    { nJogo:"", valor:"" }
];
```

O correto seria fazer deste modo:

```
$scope.numeros = [];
```

Assim, quando precisar inserir um objeto, a array já vai existir (em branco) e o novo objeto será adicionado e com o valor que o usuário inseriu.

Veja se resolve o seu problema.

Comment: A sua resposta foi perfeita, agradeço a sua ajuda nos meus estudos!

Answer (score 1):

Ai inicializar a variável do array, não precisas informar os atributos.

Somente [] já resolve.

No teu exemplo colocastes strings vazias na primeira posição. Por isso a primeira linha da tabela "parece" estar vazia.